# Thumbnail do not appear for office documents

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, icons, thumbnails, preview

The thumbnails for all Microsoft office (2010 pro) files quit working.  They show the type (word, excel, etc) icon but not a thumbnail of the actual document. All other icons (pdf,etc) that show live preview (thumbnails) work just fine.  So far I have done these...

1. I restarted the computer.  That usually fixes several issues, but not this time.
2. I've made sure that when you "save as," the check box next to the "show thumbnails" is checked.  These are all files that I've used for some time (years for some like spreadsheets) that used to show thumbnails.  This is not the issue. But I double checked several files anyways.  They all have this check box checked.
3. In "Folder View Options" >> Always show icons, never thumbnails >> is UNCHECKED.  AND, it's only the Office thumbnails.  Everything else works fine.
4. I recently cleaned out ALL Google and IE history, cookies, and all other temp cache, and disabled and deleted all unknown/unauthorized add-ins (mostly).
5. Associations of file types are not the problem.  The icons are fine.  They just don't show preview thumbnails.  In most folders, I view the icons at the Large setting.

I don't know exactly when the thumbnails stopped showing previews. I've had other things to deal with so I've let it go unfixed for several weeks. Because I don't remember the exact date, or even one close to it, I don't have a date to "roll back" any changes and/or updates I might have done, programs or apps I may have installed, etc.

Just to make sure this is clear, there is a difference between the "Preview Pane" that can be used in "Organize" >> "Layout" views and those that show thumbnail previews that are used instead of just icons.  Mine is a problem with the thumbnail previews, and it's just Microsoft Office thumbnails.  All other file types work just fine.

I use Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit).

Hope this makes sense. I'd appreciate any and all suggestions.  Thanks in advance.